# Ag-Grid: Don't use "full width" row for LoadingCellRenderer

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm in the process of writing a custom LoadingCellRenderer for ag-grid. We're trying to display skeletons of the columns. The content of the renderer is working fine, but because the loading cell is displayed as a full width row I can't scroll horizontally.

Can I change the loading row to be rendered as a "normal" row instead of full width.

[image: The loading cell renderer in action]

This is the code for the agLoadingCellRenderer I'd like to use.

```
export default class LoadingSkeletonRenderer {
  init({rowIndex, columnApi, api}) {
    const columns = columnApi.getAllGridColumns();

    this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
    if (api.getDisplayedRowCount() === 1) {
      return;
    }
    this.eGui.className = 'ag-ltr';
    const cols = [];
    columns.forEach((column, columnIndex) => {
      if (column.isVisible() && column.getActualWidth() > 28) {
        cols.push(
          `<div class="ag-cell" style="width: ${column.getActualWidth()}px;left:${column.getLeft()}px">` +
            `<div style="width:80%;height:19px;background:#e6e6e6">&nbsp;</div>` +
            `</div>`
        );
      }
    });
    this.eGui.innerHTML = cols.join('');
  }
  getGui() {
    return this.eGui;
  }
  refresh(params) {
    return true;
  }
  destroy() {}
}
```

I removed the styling as it's in scss modules and replaced it with (simplified) inline styles.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @Viqas I added the code of my cell renderer.

Comment: Hi @fluegu. did you find any solution for this. I was trying the same

Comment: @Jayakrishnan sorry for the late reply. Sadly I did not find a solution but AG-Grid now have a feature request open for this: AG-4599